# How to span a plane using perpendicular unit vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let $P(1,2,3)$ be a point, and let $Q(-2,-3,4)$ be a point on a plane through the origin. The line passing through $P$ and $Q$ is perpendicular to this plane. Find two perpendicular unit vectors that span this plane."

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite a while now. So far, what I've figured out is as follows:
$PQ$ vector is perpendicular to the plane in question and defined as $\langle-3,-5,1\rangle$. Then I've performed a dot product between this vector and the plane itself, equaling it to zero since they are supposed to be perpendicular and got the plane equation as $-3x-5y+z=25$.

I assume the first perpendicular unit vector could be $\frac{\langle-3,-5,1\rangle}{\sqrt{9+25+1}}$
What I fail to understand is, however, how two perpendicular vectors could be used for spanning a plane or what the second unit vector might be.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: "$Q(−2,−3,4)$ be a point on a plane through the origin". Do you mean that $Q(-2,-3,4)$ and $A(0,0,0)$ are points on the plane? If so, then $−3x−5y+z=25$ can not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

$Q-P=(-3,-5,1)$ is a norm to the plane.

So $-3(x+2)+(-5)(y+3)+(z-4)=0$

$\implies -3x-5y+z = 25$

This plane doesn't go through the origin though.

That said:  $R=(0,0,25)$ is.

$R-Q= (2,3,21)$

Normalize the normal to the plane $\hat{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{35}}<-3,-5,1> $

$||R-Q||=\hat{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{454}}<2,3,21>$

Another unit vector to span the plane is $\hat{b}=\hat{n} \times \hat{a}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{35 \cdot 454}}<-102, 65, 1>$